# How to draw triangles using CGAL?

Tags: cgal

**Problem description**
I have a list which contains many triangle_3 objects. It should look like a closed surface mesh, but I don't use a Surface_mesh to represent it for many reasons. However, I really want to check it, so I want to draw it. I read CGAL manual, but I didn't find any functions that I can use on Windows. I found a function named draw_triangles in the Geomview package, but the user manual of this package says *"The functionality described in this chapter is not available on Windows"*. It seems that it is not possible to use draw_triangles function in my programming environment. How can I draw the triangles?
**Programming environment**
windows x64
VS 2017
CGAL 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to build a `Surface_mesh` only for display purpose. You can use the following [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/Surface_mesh_2draw_surface_mesh_8cpp-example.html). If your triangle soup is not directly a valid surface mesh, you can use the functions [`orient_polygon_soup()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#gaadc5bac3072b11d2313e40043c729d0a) and [`polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga0dec58e8a0112791f72ebbe77bac074b).

See also this [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2orient_polygon_soup_example_8cpp-example.html#a3).

**EDIT**
I never tried it but it seems that you can change color globally or per face by adding a partial template specialization to the following class:

```
namespace CGAL
{

// Default color functor; user can change it to have its own face color
struct DefaultColorFunctorFaceGraph
{
  template<typename Graph>
  CGAL::IO::Color operator()(const Graph&,
                         typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::face_descriptor fh) const
  {
    if (fh==boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_face()) // use to get the mono color
      return CGAL::IO::Color(100, 125, 200); // R G B between 0-255

    return get_random_color(CGAL::get_default_random());
  }
};

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also wonder if there is a way to change the color displayed by the draw function. The mesh drawn by the function is blue,  it doesn't look very pretty in my view.

Comment: I edited my answer with some info about that.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this method, but it didn't work. Finally I found a struct named **Basic_viewer_qt** in a header file called **Basic_viewer_qt.h**. By changing the 
values of variables m_faces_mono_color and m_ambient_color in this struct, color of mesh can be changed. It seems that the variable  m_faces_mono_color control the color of single facet, and the variable m_ambient_color control the color of light.